# Logcat from Appetize on GitPod for Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gitpod

I try to setup flutter on GitPod. I signed up for a free Appetize.io API key and re-opened the example from https://www.gitpod.io/docs/introduction/languages/dart

https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/gitpod-io/template-flutter

The app is displayed on the streamed phone but when I open it crashes.

`adb logcat` does not connect to the device. (waiting for device)

Is it possible to get a `logcat` output from the Appetize instance?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to go the Appetize dashboard and debug there...

1. first start the app via the GitPod
2. next go to https://appetize.io/apps - the app is shown there and has a debug button below it